# NodeJS write into a array and read simultaneously

Tags: node.js, security, stream

I have a while loop that loads about 10000 entries into an array and then another function pops them one at a time to be used as test inputs. The process of generating and loading those 10000 entries takes a bit of time. I'm looking for a way to to this more asynchronously i.e. once 50 entries have been created the method that uses that input can be called, at the same time it continues to generate data until it reaches 10000

Comment: You can use queue data structure for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in typescript. The idea is to generate the test cases using a generator (es6 specific), then a reader is used to buffer the generated test cases. Finally the tester is represented by a Transform stream which tests each data given it and either throws some exception or ignores a failing test, or returns an appropriate message if the test case passes. Simply pipe the test generator (reader) to the tester (transform), *and possibly pipe to some output stream to write passed and failed test cases*.

Code (typescript):

```
class InputGen<T> extends Readable {
    constructor(gen: IterableIterator<T>, count: number) {
        super({
            objectMode: true,
            highWaterMark: 50,
            read: (size?: number) => {
                if (count < 0) {
                    this.push(null);
                } else {
                    count--;
                    let testData = gen.next();
                    this.push(testData.value);
                    if (testData.done) {
                        count = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

class Tester extends Transform {
    constructor() {
        super({
            objectMode: true,
            transform: (data: any, enc: string, cb: Function) => {
                // test data
                if (/* data passes the test */!!data) {
                    cb(null, data);
                } else {
                    cb(new Error("Data did not pass the test")); // OR cb() to skip the data
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
new InputGen(function *() {
    for (let v = 0; v < 100001; v++) {
        yield v; // Some test case
    }
}(), 10000).pipe(new Tester); // pipe to an output stream if necessary
```